# Draw background region on paper

Tags: java, graphics

I am writing a Java application that draws strings on a A4 paper.
Here is my simple code:

```
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize)); 
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);


        /* Header */
        g.drawString("Information", 40, 30);
        g.drawString("More information", 40, 60);
```

I want the header region to have a background color, I don't want to background the text (most questions was on that) I want a larger background that will contain the header strings. If you can imagine a rectangle where the two Strings are placed inside.

Lastly another problem that I faced is that I can't find the dimensions of the A4-landscape. for example I want this background colour to cover the whole width of the A4 paper and the height something smaller, small enough to cover the 2 strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw large background try to fill rectangle using `Graphics2D.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double())` and draw your text on it, and to get A4 format use `PrinterJob.pageDialog()` to choose the format you want to use for printing, here is some code to start with:

```
public class Main
{

    public Main()
    {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat format = job.pageDialog(job.defaultPage());
        job.setPrintable(new Text(), format);

        if (job.printDialog())
        {
            try
            {
                job.print();
            }
            catch (PrinterException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Main();
    }
}

class Text implements Printable
{
    int textPosY;

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int index) throws PrinterException
    {
        if (index > 0)
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());

        g2d.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 10, format.getWidth(), g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight() * 2));

        /* Header */
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPosY = 10 + g2d.getFontMetrics().getAscent();
        g2d.drawString("Information", 30, textPosY);
        textPosY += g2d.getFontMetrics().getDescent() + g2d.getFontMetrics().getLeading() + g2d.getFontMetrics().getAscent();
        g2d.drawString("More information", 40, textPosY);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There is any other option to do exactly the same but now the border to be transparent and with only border around this rectangle?

Comment: @John the pdf file border are transparent, it's just i added with paint the black border to show you the A4 file format, to have only border around your text replace `g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(...))`  by  `g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(...));`